# How can I setup vSphere so that VLAN tags are not stripped at the vSwitch?

Tags: networking, vmware-esx, vlan, vmware-vsphere

I am trying to test a VLAN-related networking issue, so I thought that firing up a couple virtual machines would be the easiest and cleanest method to test the problem.  On the vSphere server I created a new vSwitch with no adapters bound, then created a new VM Network with VLAN tag 0 (disabled.)

I created two VMs and put those VMs on the new VM Network.  They can talk to each other so long as VLAN tagging is not involved, but as soon as I assign their interfaces to a specific VLAN inside the operating system, they cannot communicate on the VLAN.

It appears that vSphere is stripping the VLAN tags somehow.  Does anyone know if there's a way to make vSphere **NOT** strip VLANs it's not expecting at the vSwitch?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to check this [VMware KB about VM VLAN Tagging Mode](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004252). This explains what to do on ESX 3.X but applies to 4 and 5 too.

Basically you need to enable trunk mode on the vSwitch by using VLAN ID 4095 to let your guests do the tagging.

Comment: Thanks pfo!  I tried this and it did exactly what I was looking for.  Kudos!